# How to set up email forward via DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, mail-forwarding

We currently have old_domain.com as the primary domain in google mail and new_domain.com as an alias. We want to change new_domain.com to the primary domain. Unfortunately google has a 24 hour lock on the alias so we can't simply swap the domains without downtime. How can we set up email forwarding via DNS/MX records? We want each users to receive their emails on their old domain (*@new_domain.com -> *@old_domain.com) while we migrate.

Comment: You can't with *just* dns records.  DNS simply says what server should receive messages for a specific domain.  You must have a server configured to receive for that domain and send it on to the new address.

Comment: You will need to reconfigure the mail server at new_domain.com's MX to forward the emails.  If you would name the software that server runs you might get specific help.

Answer (score -1):

Point your MX record for your email domain to the Google mail server name they issued to you.  So, yes.  Your answered your own question.  Use MX records in DNS.   Good luck and enjoy the uptime.

Comment: That requires setting the domain as an alias in google, we're trying to move off of that.

Comment: Google is your DNS hosting as well as your mail then?

Comment: You can have a single mail server receiving mail for multiple DNS domain names.  Perhaps I don't understand what your trying to do then.

Comment: this is a horribly vague answer and not helpful really - 'go read the documentation'